# Proving that there exists a $\xi\in \mathbb{R} $ such that $\ln f(\xi) = \xi$.

Tags: analysis, derivatives

> Given a function $f(x)$ that is differentiable over
> $(-\infty,+\infty)$, and $|f'(x)| < k f(x)$ for some $0 < k < 1$.
> Prove that there exists a $\xi\in  \mathbb{R}$
> such that $\ln f(\xi) = \xi$.

I attempt a proof by contradiction but couldn't proceed. First, we assume that $F(x) = \ln f(x) - x<0$ ( or $>0$) consistently. Since $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{d}{dx} \ln f(x)$$ we obtain $$|\frac{d}{dx} \ln f(x)| < k < 1,$$ which lead to $F'(x) < 0$ consistently, indicating a strictly decreasing function. However, at this point, I struggle to establish $\ln f(x) < x$ consistently, resulting in a contradiction.

I would appreciate it if someone could provide some insights. Thank you very much.

Comment: Show that if $F(0)>0$, $F(F(0)/(1-k))<0$. Other case is similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G(x)=F(0)+(k-1)x$, then

- $F(0)=G(0)$,
- $F'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}-1<k-1=G'(x)$.

This means $F(x)<=G(x)$ for $x\geq0$ and $F(x)>=G(x)$ for $x\leq0$.

Now let $c=-F(0)/(k-1)$, we have

- if $F(0)>0$, then $c>0$ and $F(c)\leq G(c)=0$;
- if $F(0)<0$, then $c<0$ and $F(c)\geq G(c)=0$.

In both cases, there exists $x$ between $0$ and $c$ such that $F(x)=0$ since $F$ is continuous.